# 1 Resultados duplicados con INNER JOIN

Tags: php, mysql, sql

gracias por dejarme registrar acá.

En esta oportunidad soy programadora de una nueva red social la cual llevo un día con un solo problema. Tengo 3 tablas y de las 3 tablas una se me esta duplicando las imágenes o triplicando.

```
<?php

            $query="SELECT 
                      clit.id_cliente,
                      clit.pais,
                      clit.nom_cli,
                      Vis.id_cliente,
                      Vis.ID,
                      Vis.video,
                      Vis.date,
                      fulls.id_cliente,
                      fulls.ID,
                      fulls.name,
                      fulls.foto 
              FROM cliente clit 
                      INNER JOIN videos Vis  ON clit.id_cliente = Vis.id_cliente
                      INNER JOIN fullsuave fulls ON clit.id_cliente = fulls.id_cliente
                      AND clit.id_cliente = clit.id_cliente
              ORDER BY clit.id_cliente, clit.id_cliente      
                        LIMIT 0, 25; ";  

?>
```

Por que la duplicación por favor podrían ayudarme?

Comment: Bienvenida. Si compartes la estructura de tus tablas podremos ayudarte mejor. No vendría mal que explicaras brevemente de qué se trata, para comprender mejor el contexto. De entrada, no veo qué sentido tiene esto: `AND clit.id_cliente = clit.id_cliente`  ... y otra cosa muy importante es que verifiques si realmente los datos están bien guardados en tus tablas, si tienes bien establecidas las restricciones de unicidad, etc, etc. Los duplicados pueden ser porque así están guardados, o porque en efecto la consulta no está bien.

Comment: Hola Cedano gracias por tu cordial bienvenida, si claro.
Tabla cliente
Tabla fullsuave
Tabla videos

Comment: En el FROM cliente estoy nombrando la tabla cliente y en los INNER JOIN estoy llamando las tablas videos y fullsuave. Ya lo demas son columnas que están llenas.

Comment: Eso se entiende perfectamente porque se puede ver en la consulta. Si es posible explica por qué las tablas `videos` y `fullsuave` se relacionan con la tabla `cliente` y pon un breve ejemplo de cómo tienes los datos guardados en cada tabla y del resultado que esperas obtener. A veces resulta que el usuario está implementando un mal diseño por lo que viendo los datos se te pueden hacer recomendaciones en ese sentido.

Comment: Perfecto, disculpa la lentitud tengo el internet muy lento y no me esta dejando trabajar rápido por lo mismo, para que vallas visualizando como se ven los resultados duplicados solo de las fotos mas no de los vídeos y el ID de las fotos lógico se duplican junto con la foto.  El titulo dice ID Vídeo pero toma es el de la foto. Aquí te dejo un enlace con la imagen mientras tomo las imagen de las tablas: https://i.imgur.com/quf5DYR.png

Comment: A ver, si tú ejecutas un `SHOW CREATE TABLE cliente;` y otros dos igual para las otras tablas, copias el resultado que muestra (el texto) y lo colocas en la pregunta editándola, con eso sería suficiente  y un breve ejemplo de datos. Las imágenes sirven de muy poco en estos casos. Es que ni siquiera se entiende lo que es la tabla `fullsuave`, qué hace, por qué se relaciona con la tabla `cliente`, etc. Sin ese mínimo de explicación es imposible poder ayudarte.

Comment: Aqui estan las tablas en esta imagen, estoy utilizando para llamar los videos, y las imagenes salen de la tabla fullsuave entre otros datos como name que es el apodo que desee colocar el usuario al registrarse y la tabla cliente esta el nombre verdadero del usuario y su edad, ciudad, pais, etc.: i.imgur.com/dlOlnqV.png

Comment: Bueno voy a tener que construir un modelo porque no hay forma de que compartas tu estructura de datos. Ahora vuelvo...

Comment: Revisa la respuesta que acabo de agregar a ver si te sirve. Sin entenderse lo que quieres hay que andar adivinando como comprenderás si el interesado facilita las cosas las respuestas serían más acertadas.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Reproduciendo tu modelo, después de haber intentado por todos los medios que nos indiques la estructura de tus tablas, se puede verificar que **si los datos están bien** no hay ningún problema en obtener los resultados esperados.

Por ejemplo, en un diseño donde el cliente 1 tiene dos vídeos, la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT 
    c.cliente_id, 
    c.cliente_nom,
    v.video,
    f.foto
FROM cliente_20180725 c
INNER JOIN video_20180725 v ON c.cliente_id=v.cliente_id 
INNER JOIN full_20180725  f ON c.cliente_id=f.cliente_id ;
```

Arroja el siguiente resultado:

```
cliente_id  cliente_nom      video                      foto
-------------------------------------------------------------------
1            Cliente 1        Vídeo 1 Cliente 1         foto1.jpg
1            Cliente 1        Vídeo 2 Cliente 1         foto1.jpg
2            Cliente 2        Vídeo 1 Cliente 2         foto2.jpg
3            Cliente 3        Vídeo 1 Cliente 3         foto3.jpg
```

Tampoco se sabe exactamente lo que quieres. Si por ejemplo necesitas agrupar los vídeos por cliente, etc.

Todo eso se puede hacer con relativa facilidad, siempre y cuando seas clara en explicar los resultados esperados.

Aplicar un orden determinado también es fácil.

---

### Datos de prueba

Estos son los datos que he usado. Es un ejemplo mínimo, no tiene restricciones de unicidad ni índices establecidos.

Si no he entendido bien el modelo de datos o si hay algo que no queda claro puedes indicarlo en comentario.

Espero sea útil y ayude a clarificar o resolver el problema.

<kbd>[**VER DEMOSTRACIÓN EN REXTESTER**](http://rextester.com/XXODU13246)</kbd>

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS cliente_20180725 
(
    cliente_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    cliente_nom VARCHAR(50)
)ENGINE=INNODB;

INSERT INTO cliente_20180725 (cliente_nom) VALUES 
    ('Cliente 1'),
    ('Cliente 2'),
    ('Cliente 3'),
    ('Cliente 4')
    ;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS video_20180725 
(
    video_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    cliente_id   INT,
    video VARCHAR(50),
    FOREIGN KEY (cliente_id) REFERENCES cliente_20180725(cliente_id) 
    ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE  CASCADE
)ENGINE=INNODB;

INSERT INTO video_20180725 (cliente_id,video) VALUES 
    (1,'Vídeo 1 Cliente 1'),
    (1,'Vídeo 2 Cliente 1'),
    (2,'Vídeo 1 Cliente 2'),
    (3,'Vídeo 1 Cliente 3')
    ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS full_20180725 
(
    full_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    cliente_id   INT,
    foto VARCHAR(50),
    FOREIGN KEY (cliente_id) REFERENCES cliente_20180725(cliente_id) 
    ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE  CASCADE
)ENGINE=INNODB;

INSERT INTO full_20180725 (cliente_id,foto) VALUES 
    (1,'foto1.jpg'),
    (2,'foto2.jpg'),
    (3,'foto3.jpg'),
    (4,'foto4.jpg')
    ;

SELECT 
    c.cliente_id, 
    c.cliente_nom,
    v.video,
    f.foto
FROM cliente_20180725 c
INNER JOIN video_20180725 v ON c.cliente_id=v.cliente_id 
INNER JOIN full_20180725  f ON c.cliente_id=f.cliente_id 
ORDER BY c.cliente_id LIMIT 0,25;
```

---

### EDICIÓN

Si quieres agrupar por cliente, puedes escribir la consulta así:

```
SELECT 
    c.cliente_id, 
    c.cliente_nom,
    GROUP_CONCAT(v.video SEPARATOR '|')  videos,
    f.foto
FROM cliente_20180725 c
INNER JOIN video_20180725 v ON c.cliente_id=v.cliente_id 
INNER JOIN full_20180725  f ON c.cliente_id=f.cliente_id 
GROUP BY c.cliente_id,f.foto ORDER BY c.cliente_id 
LIMIT 0,25;
```

Esta consulta te traerá una fila por cada cliente y los vídeos agrupados por un separador `|`, los cuales puedes desglosar luego por programación.

```
cliente_id       cliente_nom     videos                                     foto
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1                Cliente 1       Vídeo 2 Cliente 1|Vídeo 1 Cliente 1        foto1.jpg
2                Cliente 2       Vídeo 1 Cliente 2                          foto2.jpg
3                Cliente 3       Vídeo 1 Cliente 3                          foto3.jpg
```

Comment: Disculpa tienes razon, lo que deseo ya esta estructurado solo quiero que se vean las fotos y los videos de ese usuario unicamente y si se estan visualizando de ese usuario pero se duplica y triplica sus fotos subidas en la red social, cuando el usuario le de clic en ver mis fotos y videos se encuentre con esta imagen https://i.imgur.com/quf5DYR.png pero que no se dupliquen las fotos, no se si me entiendes? todo va bien solo que se duplican o triplican las imagenes que tiene el usuario publicadas en la websitie...

Comment: Aqui esta la imagen que creo que deseas para entender un poco: https://i.imgur.com/B6c0pRc.png

Comment: @MariaAlejandraCordero Si el cliente tiene varios vídeos, entonces lo mejor sería usar una combinación de `GROUP_CONCAT` y de `GROUP BY`, para obtener una fila por cada cliente y luego obtener los diferentes vídeos del mismo explotando el separador, por código. En este caso, recibes los vídeos del cliente `1` separados por `|`. Luego, desde PHP puedes hacer un `explode` sobre la columna `videos` para presentar los distintos vídeos de ese cliente, por ejemplo en una grilla. Revisa el apartado **EDICIÓN** que acabo de agregar al final de la respuesta.

Comment: @MariaAlejandraCordero no logro entender cuál es el problema. He hecho todo lo que he podido para proporcionar una consulta que funcione. De hecho funciona. Creo que tu problema es otro, quizá una mala organización de los datos o de todo el programa. Tu último comentario no sé que significa o qué relación pueda tener con el problema concreto que planteas aquí.

Comment: Disculpa pense que el unico problema que tenia era que se duplican las fotos y me estoy dando cuenta que tengo otro y es que con 3 usuarios diferentes he entrado a la web para ver sus fotos y videos y se ven los mismo que el primer usuario no se donde colocar el  id_cliente=".$_SESSION['id_usuario']."  para identificar las fotos y video de ese usuario al entrar a la web

Comment: @MariaAlejandraCordero ese es otro problema diferente y debería ser planteado en otra pregunta. No se pueden mezclar las preguntas porque este sitio no funciona como un foro. Una cosa es hacer que la consulta funcione y la otra lo que dices de la variable de SESION.

Comment: Si tambien lo pense en hacer otra pregunta al resolver esta para que se entienda la socluion y quede a futuro este comentario solucionado por aca, claro con tu ayuda, pero si me entendiste en la primera consulta que se siguen repitiendo o duplicando las imagenes, sera que hago una seccion para fotos y otra para videos y asi no mezclar una visualizacion de fotos y videos de usuarios juntas??? o si le vez solucion a los duplicados?

Comment: Hola A. Cedano no va ha ayudarme?

Comment: En la edición de la respuesta te expliqué una forma de obtener los datos agrupados (fíjate en los vídeos del cliente 1 como ejemplo). Luego usas el separador para mostrar cada vídeo. ¿Entiendes a lo que me refiero?

Comment: a ok ya intente pero no se ven los videos por que si me voy a el MySql a la opcion de Consulta SQL y coloco: 

SELECT c.id_cliente, c.nom_cli, GROUP_CONCAT(v.video SEPARATOR '|') videos, f.foto FROM cliente c INNER JOIN videos v ON c.id_cliente=v.id_cliente INNER JOIN fullsuave f ON c.id_cliente=f.id_cliente GROUP BY c.id_cliente,f.foto ORDER BY c.id_cliente LIMIT 0,25

Me arroja las columnas de los videos en una sola:-S-dJOdegYw|kFMZUxX6K6o|BDOM7pA43X4|pEMrVX4iH8E|X8 por el GROUP_CONCAT(v.video SEPARATOR '|')  videos, que puedo hacer para que no se mezclen las columnas de videos?

Comment: Creo que por que estas llamando la tabla videos pero no las columnas video, sera por eso?

Comment: ¿Los vídeos que se muestran separados por `|` no son todos los vídeos de ese cliente ? Si no es así entonces el problema está en que tienes los datos mal en las tablas.

Answer (score 0):

por lo que veo en tu segundo join tienes

AND clit.id_cliente = clit.id_cliente

eso esta referenciando a la la tabla cliente a si misma, eso esta mal, pero para saber el problema completo seria bueno saber las estructuras de tus tablas

Comment: Hola como estas Victor, aqui les envio la imagen de las tablas que estoy utilizando para llamar los videos, imagenes y datos del usuario en la tabla cliente.: https://i.imgur.com/dlOlnqV.png